# Error when joining CTEs

Tags: oracle, join

I have 2 CTE.When i try to join them i get an error message "ORA-01789: ".how can i merge the 2 CTE.Is there any other way to get the desired result?

```
WITH IMPORT_CTE 
AS  ((select A.*
FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 A
INNER JOIN (select distinct POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
             FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 
             GROUP BY POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
on  A.POD_ID = B.POD_ID AND A.CONFLICTED_POD_ID = B.CONFLICTED_POD_ID AND A.ERROR_CODE = B.ERROR_CODE  ) order by a.pod_id desc)
select t1.*
from IMPORT_CTE t1
where t1.insert_date =(select max(t2.insert_date)
                        from IMPORT_CTE t2
                       where t2.POD_ID =t1.POD_ID)


WITH IMPORT_CTE1 
AS  ((select A.*
FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 A
INNER JOIN (select distinct POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
             FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 
             GROUP BY POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
on  A.POD_ID = B.POD_ID AND A.CONFLICTED_POD_ID = B.CONFLICTED_POD_ID AND A.ERROR_CODE = B.ERROR_CODE  ) order by a.pod_id desc)
select t1.insert_date 
from IMPORT_CTE1 t1
where t1.insert_date =(select min(t2.insert_date)
                        from IMPORT_CTE1 t2
                       where t2.POD_ID =t1.POD_ID)
```

Comment: You forgot to tell about your *desired result*

Comment: How are you joining them?

Comment: @Prdp the desired result is joining the two queries.but i cannot join using union as the number of columns being fetched in both the queries is different

Comment: @AlexPoole I tried joining using union all but it is not working

Comment: As far as I can see the CTEs are the same, so you want a single query against the CTE which unions the two you have now - so you get the min and max dates? The error about the number of columns seems pretty clear. Why do you want to do this with a union at all though?

Comment: i thought union is the only way to get the result.how else can i get it in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an extra set of parentheses in each of your queries. The first one should apparently be:

```
WITH IMPORT_CTE AS
      (select A.*
         FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 A
         INNER JOIN (select distinct POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
                       FROM IMPORT_REGISTRY_ERROR_LOG_1 
                       GROUP BY POD_ID,CONFLICTED_POD_ID,ERROR_CODE
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B
           on A.POD_ID = B.POD_ID AND
              A.CONFLICTED_POD_ID = B.CONFLICTED_POD_ID AND
              A.ERROR_CODE = B.ERROR_CODE
         order by a.pod_id desc)
select t1.*
  from IMPORT_CTE t1
  where t1.insert_date = (select max(t2.insert_date)
                            from IMPORT_CTE t2
                            where t2.POD_ID = t1.POD_ID)
```

The second one has a similar problem.

Best of luck.